# How to get start time and end time of each process?

Tags: kernel, task, scheduler

Is there a way to get the timing of the beginning and end of each process in linux systems? if i use standard tools like top and ps, i can obtain only start_time for each process.

Answer (score 0):

ps lets you define the output format, like so:

```
ps -o pid,tty,stime,etime,cmd
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply. By this command i can get start time and elapsed time. I need know the end time of each process. Is there an option that give me this value?